# Check the switch case execution successful

Tags: php, switch-statement

I've created a `PHP` script which will check the connected database for some predefined tables and if the tables are not there script will create those tables.

In this script I've used a `switch ... case` to create the tables this is working with out any errors.

Now what I'm want to do is to check if the `switch ... case` ended with out any errors. If there's no errors then I want to fire another set or `sql` statements which will create some tasks to be run every day.

This is my table check and creation `PHP` part,

```
<?php
//This is the array that contains all the table names
    $tableNames = array(
        'catdb', 'clientdb', 'qcerrors', 'searchterm', 'teams', 'tempdb', 'userlogin', 'userroles', 'usertimetrack'
    );

    //I'm using this for loop to loop through the array and create the tables
    //if they doesn't exists.
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tableNames); $i++) {
        $tableCheck = $dbConnect->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $tableNames[$i] . "'");
        if ($tableCheck->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo $tableNames[$i] . " .... Exists <br />";
        } else {
            $tblName = $tableNames[$i];

            switch ($tblName) {
                case "catdb":
                    try {
                        $tblCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catdb` (
                                        `catId` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                        `uId` int(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `Catagory` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `createDate` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        PRIMARY KEY (`catId`)
                                        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
                        $dbConnect->exec($tblCreate);
                        echo $tblName . " .... Created OK <br />";
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo $tblCreate . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    break;

                case "clientdb":
                    try {
                        $tblCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientdb` (
                                        `clientId` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                        `catId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `uId` int(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `Client` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `cDate` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        PRIMARY KEY (`clientId`)
                                        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
                        $dbConnect->exec($tblCreate);
                        echo $tblName . " .... Created OK <br />";
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo $tblCreate . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    break;

                case "qcerrors":
                    try {
                        $tblCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qcerrors` (
                                    `qcId` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                    `qcError` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                    `createdBy` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
                                    `createdOn` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
                                    PRIMARY KEY (`qcId`)
                                    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
                        $dbConnect->exec($tblCreate);
                        echo $tblName . " .... Created OK <br />";
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo $tblCreate . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    break;

                case "searchterm":
                    try {
                        $tblCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `searchterm` (
                                    `sId` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                    `sDate` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                    `sUid` int(100) NOT NULL,
                                    `searchedBy` int(100) NOT NULL,
                                    PRIMARY KEY (`sId`)
                                    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
                        $dbConnect->exec($tblCreate);
                        echo $tblName . " .... Created OK <br />";
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo $tblCreate . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    break;

                case "teams":
                    try {
                        $tblCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teams` (
                                        `tId` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                        `TeamName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `tlName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
                                        `tlSet` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        PRIMARY KEY (`tId`)
                                        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
                        $dbConnect->exec($tblCreate);
                        echo $tblName . " .... Created OK <br />";
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo $tblCreate . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    break;

                case "tempdb":
                    try {
                        $tblCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tempdb` (
                                        `tempId` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                        `uId` int(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `tId` int(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `catId` int(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `clientId` int(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `startTime` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `Status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        PRIMARY KEY (`tempId`)
                                        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
                        $dbConnect->exec($tblCreate);
                        echo $tblName . " .... Created OK <br />";
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo $tblCreate . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    break;

                case "userlogin":
                    try {
                        $tblCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userlogin` (
                                        `uId` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                        `uCreateDate` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `createdBy` int(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `fName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `lName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `uName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `pWord` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `uTeam` int(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `uRole` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        PRIMARY KEY (`uId`)
                                        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
                        $dbConnect->exec($tblCreate);
                        echo $tblName . " .... Created OK <br />";
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo $tblCreate . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    break;

                case "userroles":
                    try {
                        $tblCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userroles` (
                                        `urId` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                        `userRole` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        PRIMARY KEY (`urId`)
                                        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
                        $dbConnect->exec($tblCreate);
                        echo $tblName . " .... Created OK <br />";
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo $tblCreate . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    break;

                case "usertimetrack":
                    try {
                        $tblCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usertimetrack` (
                                        `utId` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                        `jDate` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `usrId` int(100) NOT NULL,  
                                        `Category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `utClient` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `jType` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `startTime` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `endTime` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `timeSpent` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `Volume` int(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `qcErrorId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                        `noOfProductLines` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
                                        `Remarks` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
                                        PRIMARY KEY (`utId`)
                                        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
                        $dbConnect->exec($tblCreate);
                        echo $tblName . " .... Created OK <br />";
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo $tblCreate . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    echo $tblName . " this table is not part of this system.<br />";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Now after the above code runs with out any error I want to run below `SQL` statements which will create the tasks.

```
<?php
$timeNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //To get the current time
//Set the event scheduler status from OFF to ON
$dbConnect->exec("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON");

//Creates the daily task 1 to truncate searchterm table
$createTask1 = "CREATE DEFINER= '" . $dbUser . "'@`%` EVENT `searcTerm Table Clean` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '" . $timeNow . "' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO TRUNCATE TABLE searchterm";
$dbConnect->exec($createTask1);

//Creates the daily task 1 to truncate tempdb table
$createTask2 = "CREATE DEFINER= '" . $dbUser . "'@`%` EVENT `EmptyData` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '" . $timeNow . "' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO TRUNCATE TABLE tempdb";
$dbConnect->exec($createTask2);
?>
```

I did search google and SO but didn't see an answer that's why I decided to ask the question. I hope I've made my problem clear to the community if so can some one shed some light on what to do in order to check the `switch ... case` ended with out any errors.

Comment: MyISAM?  Really?

Comment: Can you tell me a better one then, please was using the default engine in `MySQL`.

Comment: InnoDB is the default for MySQL and has been for years.  You are using a relatively recent version of MySQL, right?  Also, Latin 1 might come beck to haunt you in the future, why not use UFT8MB4?

Comment: Yes I'm using v5.714 which came with WAMP. Was not paying much attention to that really. So should I switch the engine to `InnoDB` and change the charset to `UTF8MB4`?

Comment: You definitely should change the engine to InnoDB.  Whether you should use UTF8MB4 is a bit more dependant on your use case but as a rule it can encode pretty much everything (including emoji) and Latin 1 can't

Comment: Ok will do as soon as I finish with the coding of my setup system for the web program I'm building I will change the engine and the char set. And thank you for letting me know about it, Also [this](https://github.com/sandmaan/Timmer.git) is the system I'm creating the one in Git is the most stable one it doesn't have the install system I will sync once I'm happy with it. If you have time just have a look. It's not the best coding I think but I'm building it by my self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, I see a lot of echoes in catch blocks:

```
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $tblCreate . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Before the switch statement, you could make an errors array:

```
$errors = array();
```

Then, in your catch block, you can keep the echo if you like, but add the error message to the errors array:

```
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $tblCreate . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    $errors[] = $tblCreate.' - '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Finally, when the code has finished running, you can check for errors by counting the error array:

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    // code ran successfully
} else {
    // fail
}
```

Comment: Will try this and let you and thank you for your time.